# Need help in flash loan arbitrage project

Tags: solidity, uniswap, decentralized-exchange, uniswapv3, swaps

I am creating a flash loan arbitrage project, where i am using uniswap v3 for first swap, do i need to add code for adding liquidity too? I wrote code just for swap. I know without liquidity we can't swap. Its kinda confusing. help me.

Comment: do you want your contract to add liquidity?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to add liquidity. Instead, you'll be utilizing the existing liquidity pools to perform the swaps. If there is a sufficient liquidity for the assets you are swapping, your arbitrage should be working.

When you execute a flash loan, you borrow the funds from lenders like AAVE, perform the arbitrage by swapping tokens, and then repay the loan, this all happens within a single transaction.

Comment: existing liquidity pool means the main pool of Uniswap?

Comment: yes, you are right.